# want to show more data in another component when view in detail button is clicked (angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to angular6, Please do not consider this question as duplicated, as i could not able to find relevant answer so far, I have 2 components **incident Component** and **incident-detail component**, (incident-detail component is inside incident component) I have fetched data from api in **incident.component.ts** now I have a button called **view details** in **incident.component.html** when clicked the view detail button it will navigate to **incident-detail component** using **router.navigate**, now along with this I want send data which is in incident component.ts to incident-detail component.ts so that I can bind data in incident-detail.component.html, Is there a way where I can achieve this? Thanks

folder structure

```
incident
  incident-detail.component.html
   incident-detail.component.ts
 incident.component.html
  incident.component.ts
```

incident.component.html

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let incident of incidents; let i = index"> 
<div class="card-header">
<span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident.Title}}
<span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident.Ticket}} 
</small>
<div class="card-footer">
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-link" 
(click)="onLoadActive(incident)">View in Detail</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

incident.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import { Incidents } from '../../shared/models/incidents.model';
  import { DataStorageService } from '../../shared/services/data- 
  storage.service';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-active-incident',
  templateUrl: './active-incident.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-incident.component.css']
  })
  export class ActiveIncidentComponent implements OnInit {

  detailData: any;

  private _incidents: Incidents[] = [];
  public get incidents(): Incidents[] {
  return this._incidents;
  }
  public set incidents(value: Incidents[]) {
  this._incidents = value;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private dataStorageService: 
  DataStorageService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.dataStorageService.getIncidents()
  .subscribe(
    (data: Incidents[]) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.Events.length; i++) {
        const quoteReplaceData = data.Events[i].replace(/'/g, '"');
        const objIdRemove = quoteReplaceData.replace(quoteReplaceData.substr(quoteReplaceData.indexOf('\"_id\": ObjectId'), 44), '');
        this.incidents.push(JSON.parse(objIdRemove)); // JSON.parse(data),
       console.log(this.incidents);
      }
    },
    (err: any) => console.log(err),
    () => console.log('All done getting incidents')
  );
}

onLoadActive(incident) {
  // some logic
  this.detailData = incident;
  this.router.navigate(['/active-detail']);

}
```

}

incident-detail.component.html 
need to get data from incident component

```
 <div class="card"> 
<div class="card-header">
<span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident.Title}}
<span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident.Ticket}} 
</small>
</div>
</div>
```

incident-detail.component.ts
want to get this.detailData from incident component here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-active-incident-detail',
  templateUrl: './active-incident-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./active-incident-detail.component.css']
})
export class ActiveIncidentDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Comment: You can send query string in `router.navigate`

Comment: There's another way, you can create a data sharing service. You just want `title` from incident component for incident detail component?

Comment: HI Thanks, Not title alone, there are are many fields that i need to bind on the view.

Comment: I've added the answer, you can modify that service to receive data as much you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data sharing service first, here's sample code, you should modify according to your need

**Data sharing service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataSharingService {
    private title = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
    currentTitle = this.title.asObservable();

    setTitle(txt: string){
        this.title.next(txt);
    }
}
```

inject this service into your incident component

**Data sender component**

```
constructor(
    private dataSharingService: DataSharingService
  ) { }
```

use this service where you want in your incident component before navigation

```
this.dataSharingService.setTitle("Your title or data");
```

Now you surely want to receive data into your incident detail component, for that here's sample code

**Data receiver component**

```
title: string;
  constructor(private dataSharingService: DataSharingService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSharingService.currentTitle.subscribe(data => {
      this.title = data;
    })
  }
```

**Note:** Please modify according to your requirement, this service I made to set and get `string` title. This service is useful for independent components, without any child-parent relationship.

Comment: This approach, while sometimes necessary, should not  be your first choise because it introduces shared, mutable application scoped state.

Answer (score 0):

While, the solution suggested in some of the other answers, namely using a service to broadcast data changes, for example using an RxJS `Subject`, can make this work and is at times the most natural approach, it should not be your first choice because it introduces shared, mutable application scoped state.

It should be avoided wherever possible for some of the following reasons:

1. Using the router, and by implication the URL, to control the rendered components introduces a beneficial decoupling keeping your components cleaner and rendering them independent of their relationship to one another independent of their relative layout in the view tree. This is very advantageous for maintenance and even more so for reusability.
2. By relying on the changes broadcast through a shared service, you are introducing another source of truth, implicitly relying on the router. That is to say, if the you navigate to the detail route before navigating to the list route, the detail route will not work. In order to work around that, the application becomes much more complex.

The structurally simplest approach is to have both components retrieve their data independently. This downside is additional HTTP requests and loading time but, unless you are working with very large data structures or your server takes a very long time to process the requests, it is often worth it. At the very least, you should try this approach first.

Here is what it would look like

**data.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import formatIncident from './format-incident';
import Incident from './incident';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) export class IncidentService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getIncidents() {
    return this.http.get('api/incidents')
      .pipe(
        map(data => data.Events.map(formatIncident)
      );
  }
  getIncident(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<Incident>(`api/incidents/${id}`).map(formatIncident);
  }
}
```

**format-incident.ts**

```
import Incident from './incident';

export default function formatIncident(eventJSON): Incident {
  const unquotedEventJSON = eventJSON.replace(/'/g, '"');
  const objectIdIndex = unquotedEventJSON.indexOf('"_id": ObjectId');
  const eventJSONSansId = unquotedEventJSON.substr(objectIdIndex, 44);

  const incident = JSON.parse(eventJSONSansId);
  const id = unquotedEventJSON.substr(0, objectIdIndex);

  return {
      ...incident,
      id
    };
}
```

**incident.ts**

```
export default interface Incident {
  id: string,
  Title: string;
  Ticket: string;
}
```

**incidents.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-incidents',
  templateUrl: './incidents.component.html'
})
export class IncidentsComponent {
  constructor(router: Router, incidentService: IncidentService) {
    this.router = router;
    this.incidentService = incidentService;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.incidents$ = this.incidentService.getIncidents();
  }

  incidents$?: Observable<Incident>;
}
```

**incidents.component.html**

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let incident of incidents$ | async">
  <div class="card-header">
    <span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident.Title}}</small>
    <span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident.Ticket}}</small>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-link"
            routeLink="/incidents/{{incident.id}}"
            [routerLinkActive]="router.url.match(incident.id)">View in Detail</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**incident-detail.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-incident-detail',
  templateUrl: './incident-detail.component.html'
})
export class IncidentDetailComponent {
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute, incidentService: IncidentService) {
    route.paramMap.get('incidentId')
      .pipe(
        map(id => incidentService.getIncident(id))
       )
      .subscribe(incident => {
        this.incident = incident;
      });
  }

  incident?: Incident;
}
```

**incident-detail.component.html**

```
<div class="card"> 
  <div class="card-header">
    <span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident?.Title}}</small>
    <span class="badge">A</span><small>{{incident?.Ticket}}</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
 import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';    
 import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
 import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  components: [IncidentsComponent, IncidentDetailComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'incidents', component: IncidentsComponent}, 
      {path: 'incidents/incidentId', component: IncidentDetailComponent}
    ])
   ]
}) export class AppModule {}
```

This is a bog standard approach and works well for many situations but there a few for which it is a not a great fit.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the **Decorators** for making a communication between parent and child components.
@Input and @Output are parts of the @angular/core.
The @Input decorator is for obtaining the data that is passed from a component.
@Output can pass data back from child to parent

Answer (score -1):

when your incident-detail-component is a child element of your incident-component, you can simply pass the data in as an input variable.
Take a look here:
https://angular.io/api/core/Input

Comment: Hi thanks, but incident-detail.component is not a child component of incident.component, I have data in incident.component.ts I want more data  to show in incident-detail.component.ts when i click view detail button in incident component

Comment: then you should probably get that incident-detail data in your incident-detail-data component from your api. Otherwise you will end up with no data when refreshing the page.
You can pass the identifier of the incident in your router to get like a RESTful structure and then read it in your detail component to get the full data from your API. I think that would be the best solution in your case.