# get data in component angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hi I am new angular6 how can I get data to component, I have fetched data from api in incident.component.ts now I have a button called view details in incident.component.html when clicked the view detail button it will navigate to incident-detail component using router.navigate, now along with this I want send data which is in incident component.ts to incident-detail component.

incident.component.html

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let incident of incidents; let i = index"> 
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-link" 
(click)="onLoadActive(incident)">View in Detail</button>
</div>
</div>
```

incident.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Incidents } from '../../shared/models/incidents.model';
    import { DataStorageService } from '../../shared/services/data-storage.service';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-active-incident',
    templateUrl: './active-incident.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./active-incident.component.css']
    })
   export class ActiveIncidentComponent implements OnInit {
   detailData: any;

   onLoadActive(incident) {
   // some logic
   this.detailData = incident;
   this.router.navigate(['/active-detail']);
   }
   }
```

incident-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-active-incident-detail',
templateUrl: './active-incident-detail.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./active-incident-detail.component.css']
})
export class ActiveIncidentDetailComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {
// want to get **detailData** here
}
}
```

Comment: what have you tried until now?

Comment: well I have fetched data to incident component, now on click of a button I am trying to pass incident data to incident-detail component

Comment: Possible duplicate of [want to show more data in another component when view in detail button is clicked (angular 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569073/want-to-show-more-data-in-another-component-when-view-in-detail-button-is-clicke)

Answer (score 2):

There are `distinguish ways` to pass data between `component to component`.

1) User services by use of `emit()` and `subscribe()`.

2) User `@Input()` decorator to pass data.

3) You can access data by store that data in common file's variable and fetch that data.

**Make sure if reload page then you will note able to fetch data.**

4) If amount of data's size is small then you can use `cookie` or `local-storage.`

If you use app selector of `incident-detail component` then go with second option. which is very easy to use. Otherwise go with first option.

For that, You have to create one service file.

```
E.x: common.service.ts  // shared/services/common.service.ts
```

Hear you have to make one variable.

```
import { Component, Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
incidentData = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

Now in you `indecent.ts` file.

```
import this `common.service.ts` file and add in constructor param.
```

Now `emit()` the event.

```
onLoadActive(event){
    this.commonService.incidentData.emit({data:{pass your any data hear}});
    // In this param you have to pass data which you want to send in other component. 
}
```

Now you have to `subscribe()` this event into your other component.

**In incident-detail component file.**

Step 1 : Import `common.service.ts` file.

Step 2 : Subscribe event in component's constructor.

```
viewData : any = [];  // Used to display data
constructor(private commonService : CommonService){
    this.commonservice.incidentData.subscribe((data : any) => {
         console.log("Data from parent ::: " , JSON.stringify(data));
         this.viewData = data; 
         // Now use this viewData array in you HTML file. 
    })
}
```

**In HTML file.**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of viewData">
     <p>{{data.name}}</p>
     <p>{{data.address}}</p>
</div>
```

In your case, You have used `*ngFor` loop in incedent component. And pass that data in to another data. For that also you can also use `emit()` and `subscribe()` to do that.

```
E.x: // In your parent component. You have used ngFor. 
<div *ngFor="let data of incedentData">
    <button (click)="viewData(data)">View Details</button>

     <!-- Hear you set click event and pass data of each row -->
```

**In Incedent.component.ts file**

You have same set `emit()` as I explain above.

```
viewData(viewData){
    // Hear you have to emit event and pass data. 
    this.commonService.incidentData.emit({data:viewData});
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, But I do not want use *ngFor in incident-detail component, I have used *ngFor in incident component there if I press view in detail button I want to navigate to incident-detail component with respective data.

Comment: @vinaykhegde I have update my answer to fix your issue. I hope it'll helps you. :)

Comment: Hi I used BehaviorSubject<string>("") to get data.

Comment: @vinaykhegde ok and have you tried to implement my solution to fixed your issue? If yes then can you please give comment on that ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to pass data into a component, with 'property binding' and 'event binding'. In Angular, data and event change detection happens top-down from parent to children. However for Angular events we can use the DOM event mental model where events flow bottom-up from child to parent. So, Angular events can be treated like regular HTML DOM based events when it comes to cancellable event propagation.
The @Input() decorator defines a set of parameters that can be passed down from the component's parent. For example, we can modify the TestComponent component so that name can be provided by the parent.

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: '<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>',
})
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

The point of making components is not only encapsulation, but also reusability. Inputs allow us to configure a particular instance of a component.
We can now use our component like this:

```
<!-- To bind to a raw string -->
<test name="World"></test>
<!-- To bind to a variable in the parent scope -->
<test [name]="helloName"></test>
```

And dont forget to import your component in your typescript file.